# Tensor product commutes with homology for a "flat chain complex" -- A step for proving the universal coefficient theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

I'm trying to prove the universal coefficient theorem (**UCT**) for homology and cohomology using spectral sequences following Section 5.6 of Weibel's book *Introduction to homological algebra* and coming up with the following problem:

**Question**: Let $C_{\bullet} = (C_{n} \xrightarrow{d} C_{n-1})$ be a chain complex and $P$ be a projective $R$-module. If each object $C_n$ is a flat $R$-module, then does the following equality (or say isomorphism) holds:
$$
H_n (C_{\bullet} \otimes_{R} P) = H_n (C_{\bullet}) \otimes_{R} P. 
$$

**Attempt**: We shall note that every projective $R$-module is flat, so universal coefficient theorem does the trick. **BUT I'm proving UCT, so we shouldn't use UCT to show this.** Then how to show this without UCT?

Similarly, I came up with the following coquestion for the cohomology:

**Coquestion**: Let $C_{\bullet} = (C_{n} \xrightarrow{d} C_{n-1})$ be a chain complex and $I$ be an injective $R$-module. If each object $C_n$ is a projective $R$-module, then does the following equality (or say isomorphism) holds:
$$
H^n (\mathrm{Hom}_R(C_{\bullet},I)) = \mathrm{Hom}_R(H_n(C_{\bullet}),I). 
$$

**Coattempt**: In this case, we even lost the trick of UCT, as we do not have the parallel statement for "projective $\Rightarrow$ flat", and clearly injectivity does not imply projectivity in general. **So I doubt that actually the isomorphism in Question and Coquestion hold even without condition on $P$ and $I$ accordingly.** Then how to show these isomorphisms?

Thank you all for commenting and answering! :)

Comment: For your question, flatness of $C$ doesn’t matter, I think, it’s just that $-\otimes P$ is an exact functor so it commutes to homology. Same thing for your coquestion.

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you! Silly of me :(

Comment: +1 for the formulation "coquestion, coattempt".